# How can I pre-configure the IP address of a pod in Kubernetes (GCP)?

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to automate the process of dynamically bring up two containers in a Kubernetes cluster using open-source images. Since the images are third party images, I have some limitations to what can be configured. I also need these containers to come up inside different pods.

For the sake of this discussion, I will call these containers container `a.domain.com` and container `b.domain.com`. Container A and B need to communicate back and forth and this communication is secured using TLS Certificates.

To enable this communication, I have to add the following code snippet to the spec to of my Kubernetes deployment doc.

```
#deployment doc for a.domain.com
spec:
  hostAliases:
  - ip: <Insert IP address for b.domain.com>
    hostnames:
    - "b.domain.com"

#deployment doc for b.domain.com
spec:
  hostAliases:
  - ip: <Insert IP address for a.domain.com>
    hostnames:
    - "a.domain.com"
```

If this code is missing, I get the following errors:

```
Error on container a.domain.com: No such host - b.domain.com
Error on container b.domain.com: No such host - a.domain.com
```

Since, both my containers have to come up together, I cannot hardcode the IP address in the yaml file.

Is there anyway I can add a parameter to the deployment docs for these containers that allows me to deterministically pre-configure the IP address that the pods use when they come up?

Comment: Pods are meant to be ephemeral, thus communication with them through IP is not recommended. You should look at Services instead.

Comment: I don't know the answer. However, I do not think that you can. Pods are created and destroyed and are assigned IP addresses from a pool. Normally you want to use service discovery and not hard-coded information.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried services already. I have created services for both the pods and can access them using `service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local` which works well everywhere else. But I cannot use this value in place of IP address under host-aliases.

Comment: @goldentiger i understand you must use `a.domain.com` as the host name?

Comment: Are you mixing Pods, container and service ? Pods are composed of one or several containers, pods are mortal, service can spawn pods according with usage. You can [define IP port on service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors). Is this answer your requirement?

Comment: I finally figured it out. Using service-name.namespace instead of service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local solved the issue for me.

Comment: @goldentiger Could you please share your solution in a form of an answer? That way the rest of the community could benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the OP's comment as an answer (community wiki):

> I finally figured it out. Using service-name.namespace instead of service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local solved the issue for me.